# Why was this API comparison question closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question [ServiceStack vs ASP.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699083/servicestack-vs-asp-net-web-api) which was closed. While I understand the reasoning behind the closure (as per [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)) there have been a lot of comments to reopen the question. It would be nice to see the question reopened (as I agree that it has value), but I'm not sure on how to rephrase it in order to be a better fit. Could I get some pointers?

Comment: Probably looks at bit too much like a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Any advice on how to change it?

Comment: ["Gorilla vs. Shark"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) might also be relevant here. Can you make this a more specific comparison between the two? I'd probably also remove the "Has anyone looked at the new Web API project?" language, because that sounds too close to an audience poll, which rarely ends well. There's a good, constructive question in there, but I'm not sure of the exact phrasing to use.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson that helps. Gorilla vs Shark is spot on.

Comment: There's great info in this question - I hope it gets re-opened.  I wish people would stop blindly following rules and focus on **content**

Comment: You've got an excellent answer, but why does it need to be reopened? Are you expecting more activity on it?

Comment: @Adam - Being interesting or answerable does not mean a question fits the Q&A format.

Comment: @Brad - and arguments like that continue to beg the question.  If the rules result in useful, good content like that being closed, then the rules may need updating.

Comment: Also, I'm bookmarking this as the *right* way to ask why a question was closed.

Comment: Note: there are over 4,500+ questions with `vs` in the text. Based on this assumption most of them should be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vs I hardly think a question with an answer of 50 links, to external patterns, docs and external-resources qualifies as the ideal candidate (above all the open ones) to be closed.

Comment: There are an infinite number of useful questions, but the site has a defined scope. The rules weren't just plucked out of the air, they've been *extensively* discussed, most recently in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143010/policy-enforcement-time-for-an-so-site-for-all-the-things-so-isnt). Also, [2800](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vs+closed%3A1&submit=search) of the vs. questions are already closed. Community moderation doesn't always get everything immediately, but that doesn't mean we give up and allow anything.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Oh my God, just that statement right there. Why can't the old farts realize this?

Answer (score 10):

If anything the question is a challenge between press releases and feature lists to battle it out over audience share and leather belt straps.

The pros and cons gauntlet has been laid down and the only way for that question to be answered is to have sales reps, myopic fans or advocates gloss it up.

This continues a problem with "what are the pros and cons" type questions as all you do is have camps set up firing volleys into the air, trying to win the war of loud and asking for a piece of rumcake to wash it down with.

If it was about migration from one and needing to know how to overcome a hurdle, there's a question. If it was about making the new environment work like the old, there's another valid question.

What's the problem here beyond product comparison? A blog post missing a location.